# Polymorphic Typescript Component for Social Icon Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

i am trying to create a polymorphic component for Social icons

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from 'styles/pro.module.scss';
import {
  Facebook, Instagram, Pinterest, Twitter,
} from 'react-bootstrap-icons';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
 

type SocialButtonProps =React.PropsWithChildren<{
  network: 'Instagram' | 'Facebook' | 'Pinterest' | 'Twitter' ;
    url: string ;
}>;

const SocialButton = ({
  url, network: Network, children,
}: SocialButtonProps) => (

  <Button className={`rounded-pill p-2 pro_${Network}`} variant="secondary" href={url} target="_blank">
    <Network className="fs-3 fw-bold" />

  </Button>
);


export default SocialButton;
```

it is giving me following error on `<Network className="fs-3 fw-bold" />`

```
Property 'Facebook' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.ts(2339)
Property 'Instagram' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.ts(2339)
Property 'Pinterest' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.ts(2339)
Property 'Twitter' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.ts(2339)
```

any idea what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

`Facebook, Instagram, Pinterest, Twitter` are components not strings. You need to type `network` as whatever the types of those components is (you can use `typeof` to get the type of a variable:

```
type SocialButtonProps =React.PropsWithChildren<{
  network: typeof Instagram | typeof Facebook | typeof Pinterest | typeof Twitter ;
    url: string ;
}>;

const SocialButton = ({
  url, network: Network, children,
}: SocialButtonProps) => (

  <Button className={`rounded-pill p-2 pro_${Network}`} variant="secondary">
    <Network className="fs-3 fw-bold" />

  </Button>
);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)